# web hosting and websocket technologies

Tags: web, hosting, websocket

I want to write a web application that needs a websocket server.
I want to host this websocket server on some famous web hosting provider (such as 1&1 by example).
Which web hosting provider should I use?

Comment: What server side language are you wanting to use? Any failover capability needed? Is it for a commercial use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a websocket server which you can start and stop at will I would much rather recommend a cloud solution. It's cheap and lets you interact with the server directly, which is most likely impossible with more traditional hosting providers. I've only used [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com) and [Google App Engine](http://appspot.com) myself, they both have a free tier which you can use to build and test your websocket application. There are many more providers, also have a look at PaaS services like [Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/). It all depends on what specific technologies you want to use I guess.

(note: AWS lets you SSH into your instance and you can use any platform/technology you want while GAE is web based and limited to Go, Java and Python. It doesn't mean AWS is better, again it depends on your case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebSockets for your .NET apps with GearHost at www.gearhost.com. It's free and gives you 100 free CloudSites and 100 free databases.